# Can't import .so file from another .so

Tags: python, c++, boost, shared-libraries

**Problem:**

From inside the virtual environment can't import `dlib`, which references `dlib.so` which references `libboost_python.so`:

```
(venv) serj@venus ~/work/beautytorch $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/serj/work/beautytorch/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .dlib import *
ImportError: libboost_python.so.1.64.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>>
```

**Environment:**

Compiled `Boost.Python` from sources:

```
serj@venus ~ $ ls -l /usr/local/lib | grep boost
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   670876 Jun 16 14:10 libboost_python.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root       25 Jun 16 14:10 libboost_python.so -> libboost_python.so.1.64.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root   408147 Jun 16 14:10 libboost_python.so.1.64.0
```

Put link to my virtual environment (the last two, don't know which one is correct):

```
serj@venus ~/work/beautytorch/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages $ ls -l | grep boost
drwxr-xr-x  2 serj serj   4096 Jun 16 13:40 boost
drwxr-xr-x  2 serj serj   4096 Jun 16 13:40 boost-0.1.dist-info
lrwxrwxrwx  1 serj serj     40 Jun 19 11:50 libboost_python.so -> /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so.1.64.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 serj serj     40 Jun 19 12:13 libboost_python.so.1.64.0 -> /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.so.1.64.0
```

Now trying to import `dlib`, which imports `dlib.so` which links with `libboost_python.so.1.64.0`

```
serj@venus ~/work/beautytorch/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib $ ls -l
total 14324
-rw-r--r-- 1 serj serj 14631694 Jun 16 14:16 dlib.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 serj serj     4096 Jun 16 14:16 examples
-rw-r--r-- 1 serj serj       43 Jun 16 14:16 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 serj serj      200 Jun 16 14:16 __init__.pyc

serj@venus ~/work/beautytorch/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib $ cat __init__.py
from .dlib import *
```

See dlib.so contains reference to the exact `libboost_python` library version:

[image]

**UPD** strace output:

```
open("/home/serj/work/beautytorch/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=43, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7ef51ca000
read(3, "from .dlib import *\n__version__ "..., 4096) = 43
write(2, "    ", 4    )                     = 4
write(2, "from .dlib import *\n", 20from .dlib import *
)   = 20
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7ef51ca000, 4096)            = 0
write(2, "ImportError", 11ImportError)             = 11
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "libboost_python.so.1.64.0: canno"..., 84libboost_python.so.1.64.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) = 84
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
```

Comment: Try running witr strace, and see where it tries to find the Boost lib. That may give some hints.

Comment: Added strace output, doesn't seem to be useful, however...

Comment: Huh. It seems that it doesn't even try to find that file. Weird. I have no further ideas.

Comment: Not a solution, but a workaround is to put the libboost_python.so.1.64.0 to the current directory.